# Which months are best for seeing nemophilas in Japan?

Tags: japan

I know [Hitachi Seaside Park](https://redd.it/ar2w04) is best to see nemophilias ([link to pic under](https://flickr.com/photos/kota-g/8740259689/)), but how long do they bloom? What are:

1. the start date?
2. the end date?

[image]

Comment: The follow up question, https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/48238/why-does-season-for-seeing-nemophilas-in-japan-end-in-early-may has been moved to Gardening and gotten an answer there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Hitachi Seaside Park website has [a page with this information](https://hitachikaihin.jp/en/flowers/nemophila.html). The season is relatively short, from mid-April to early-May.

Answer (score 0):

I Googled again and found https://jw-webmagazine.com/dive-into-the-ocean-of-4-5-million-blue-flowers-e7de15969e77/ -

> The best time to see Nemophila Harmony is usually late April to early May.

[See Baby Blue Eyes Flowers at Hitachi Seaside Park in Spring | Hitachi Seaside Park from Tokyo](https://alljapantours.com/japan/travel/when-to-go/See-Baby-Blue-Eyes-Flowers-at-Hitachi-Seaside-Park-in-Spring/)

> Hitachinaka City began planting flowers like the Baby Blue Eyes in Hitachi Seaside Park in 2002. In the short years since the event has become one of [Ibaraki’s most well-known sights](https://alljapantours.com/japan/travel/what-to-do/10-Things-to-Do-in-Ibaraki/). The Baby Blue Eyes are sown every year in [November](https://alljapantours.com/japan/travel/when-to-go/Things-to-Do-in-Japan-in-November/), covered during the winter under a frost-free sheet, and carefully watered and weeded.
>
> They usually bloom from about mid-April to early [May](https://alljapantours.com/japan/travel/when-to-go/Things-to-Do-in-Japan-in-May/), but sometimes weather conditions affect the season. In 2018, for instance, the peak of the bloom came ten days earlier than usual. Generally, the best time to visit the Hitachi Seaside Park is in April when the daffodils and tulips line up with the Baby Blue Eyes flowers.
>
> During the 2 or 3-week peak of the Baby Blue Eyes flowers, the city provides free shuttle buses from Ajigaura Station. A temporary additional city bus runs from Katsuta station to support the number of visitors. It’s fairly easy to access Hitachi Seaside Park in [Ibaraki Prefecture from Tokyo](https://alljapantours.com/japan/travel/what-to-do/Day-Trip-from-Tokyo-Ibaraki/), but it does take some time out of your day. A one-way trip by [public transportation](https://alljapantours.com/travel-planning/travel-tips/transportation/?sd=yes) easily takes more than two hours if you go from [Tokyo](https://alljapantours.com/japan/travel/what-to-do/20-Must-Do-Things-in-Tokyo/).
>
> Opening hours of Hitachi Seaside Park during the Baby Blue Eyes bloom are from 9:30 am to 5:00 pm. Be mindful that the park is usually closed on Mondays, but opening days change during peak seasons. Please check their website carefully when planning your trip. Admission to Hitachi Seaside Park is 450 [JPY](https://alljapantours.com/travel-planning/travel-tips/money/?sd=yes) for adults, 210 JPY for seniors, and free for children under 12 years old.